# how to remove the last row by comparing it with variable

Tags: python-3.x

if I have text document with updated lines

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

I need to remove last line in updating text document, but remove it through compare with variable key, each time it changes in previous block

```
key = 'line to remove' 

with open('D:\path\doc.txt', 'w') as searchfile:
       for line in searchfile:
           if key in line:
           searchfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this with a single file open:

```
f = open("D:\path\doc.txt","r+") # read the whole file
lines = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)                        # point to the beginning of the file
for i in lines:
    if i != "line to remove":
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```